# websocket connection fails for domain ip address

Tags: javascript, ratchet

I am trying to use websockets for my website and for some reason it will not work. My back end is fine I believe as i am using ratchet.io and have a normal websocket chat app running on port 8082. Could someone guide me in the right direction as I have read many blog articles but am not sure what to do. PS: runs fine on localhost

```
conn = new WebSocket(`wss://myIpAddress:8082?employee=${name}`);
```

Using hostgator and regular core php.
Apache web server.
firewall has been configured to accept incoming connections.
what else could it be?

UPDATE:
So it is because ratchet.io does not support ssl out of the box. You have to init the tcp server and run a different set of code before hitting server.run. Here is the new code I have which does not work for whatever reason in my chat-server.php file.

```
    $app = new \Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
    new \Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
        new \MyApp\Chat()
    )
);

$loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$secure_websockets = new \React\Socket\Server('0.0.0.0:8082', $loop);
$secure_websockets = new \React\Socket\SecureServer($secure_websockets, $loop, [
    'local_cert' => './../../ssl/certs/cert.pem', //changed from .crt to .pem 
    'local_pk' => '../../../ssl/keys/key.pem', //changed from .key to .pem
    'verify_peer' => false,
    //'allow_self_signed' => true,
]);

$secure_websockets_server = new \Ratchet\Server\IoServer($app, $secure_websockets, $loop);
$secure_websockets_server->run();
?>   `
```

The code can be seen clearly here. https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/489

Comment: You need backticks around the template literal.

Comment: If that's just a copying error, please post the actual code.

Comment: i know. Its just the way its formatted. that is not the problem

Comment: Are you getting an error in the JavaScript console?

Comment: not really. Just a big object with no real information to know what is happening. However the failing does take some time so I have a feeling its hitting the destination but maybe there are some random config stuff I am not doing.

Comment: Or maybe there's a firewall blocking port 8082.

Comment: no i made sure that is not it